# Longtable, papaja, and single-spacing

Tags: longtable, papaja

I recently wrote up a [manuscript](https://psyarxiv.com/v9g8f/) (materials available to review) and found an issue with using longtable with papaja when trying to have a single-spaced table, although I think the issue is primarily when that table is presented with another short table. I had to wrap my longtable code with the following to make it work:

```
\begin{singlespace}
\end{singlespace}
```

I created a sample Rmd and PDF file to demonstrate the issue. You can download them via my Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/hkd6t0qnhot3efx/AAB3Y7GeeO_ZczybQX6-XcQja?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have found you can adjust the line height of environments by means of header includes. All you need to do is to add a line that adjusts the line height for the `longtable` environment. So you're header includes could look as follows:

```
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{setspace}
  - \AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\singlespacing}
  - \AtBeginEnvironment{lltable}{\singlespacing}
  - \AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\singlespacing}
  - \AtBeginEnvironment{tablenotes}{\doublespacing}
  - \captionsetup[table]{font={stretch=1.5}}
  - \captionsetup[figure]{font={stretch=1.5}}
```